# How to speed-up R console autocomplete?

Tags: r, autocomplete

I find the R console autocomplete very slow, even when I have less than say 15 objects, it's so slow, almost unusable. Why is it so slow and is there a setting somewhere to make it quicker.

I am on Win 10, R 3.2.2, with an intel i-7, so hardware is not the problem, besides in any other program autocomplete speed works as it should.

Comment: Why `R 3.2.2` (Aug 2015) while the newest version is `R 3.3.1` (Jun 2016).

Comment: @m0h3n It's the problem with every version, as far as I can remember it has always been slow.